Create a view to display a field that is specified by parameter
I need to create a view in Drupal 10 that shows all nodes of a set content type that has a given field not empty.
But I want to pass the field name/id as a parameter.
So the view will return all nodes with field_1 not empty when I pass 'field_1' as parameter.
And it will return all nodes with field_2 not empty when I pass 'field_2' as a parameter.
My initial feeling is that it's not possible but I know there are magicians out there....
Thanks!

it is possible if you alter the views results. You can use hook_views_pre_render hook to alter the results by getting the parameters in the get query.

The documentation says that hook_views_pre_render hook  occurs after the quesry has been executed. I need to modify the query before it is executed so I can filter on the field that is passed as a parameter.

For altering view query you have hook_views_query_alter() :
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/11.x

Yes that's what I ended up using. Many thanks for your help
